# SQL server not sending email

Tags: sql-server, database-mail

I'm trying to use SQL server database mail, but it's not sending any test emails.

here is my set up page:

[image]

Comment: Something tells me your outgoing server is not correct.

Comment: How are you trying to send a test email?

Comment: @SeanLange As in smtp-mail.outlook.com?

Comment: @scsimon by right clicking database mail node and selecting send test mail

Comment: Well yeah...that is what you have as the outgoing smtp server. You want your mail server there.

Comment: But it is an outlook account I'm using?

Comment: Did you look in the Database Mail logs?  Right-click Database Mail and select View Database Mail Log.

Comment: So I checked it there and got this an error, mail server error

Comment: https://www.lifewire.com/what-are-the-outlook-com-smtp-server-settings-1170671 Check the "This server requires a secure connection (SSL)" box

Comment: @UnhandledExcepSean Yeah I have that in and still not working

Comment: Can you provide the full error message you are receiving? Also, are you able to connect to outlook.com and manually log in from that computer?

Comment: @UnhandledExcepSean Yep I can log in. Here's the error "01/24/2019 18:13:33,,Error,26,The mail could not be sent to the recipients because of the mail server failure. (Sending Mail using Account 4 (2019-01-24T18:13:33). Exception Message: Cannot send mails to mail server. (The SMTP server requires a secure connection or the client was not authenticated. The server response was: 5.7.57 SMTP; Client was not authenticated to send anonymous mail during MAIL FROM [LO2P265CA0127.GBRP265.PROD.OUTLOOK.COM]).<nl/>),9580,9,,24/01/2019 18:13:33,sa"

Comment: Are you sure that checkbox is checked? You picture above shows it is unchecked.

Comment: Ah, That was it!! Thank you so must Sean! if you post an answer I'll accept it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Outlook SMTP requires SSL according to this [article](https://www.lifewire.com/what-are-the-outlook-com-smtp-server-settings-1170671).

You need to check the "This server requires a secure connection (SSL)" box